# Passing variables through to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some variables that I would like to pass into an AJAX call:

e.g.

```
var moo = "cow noise";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: "",
    success: function(data){
            //return the variable here
            alert(moo);
    }
});
```

However, `moo` comes back undefined.

*note*, I've left `url` and `data` empty on purpose - they are populated in my code.

Comment: I can't detect any problem. Please provide the actual code or a working bug.

Comment: Please include the actual code. Your current example if perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the problem .I don't see any error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess your code might have been wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });` as an jQuery thing. remove `var` will make it basically `window.moo = "cow noise";` Which works, but pollutes the namespaces which is not what you want.

Do not try to pollute the global namespace, it will make your other code hard to debug.
Use closure which should solve your issue:

```
var moo = "cow noise";

(function(moo){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: "",
        success: function(data){
            //return the variable here
            alert(moo);
        }
    });
})(moo);
```

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with your code example, the original code is fine as well and this is not a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This should work, can't see anything wrong with your code. [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tf7G/).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why do you think this answer is wrong. Also did you visit the jsfiddle link I provided which illustrates the exact same code working in action?

Comment: Upvoting to correct. I don't see any reason why this was downvoted.

Comment: This isn't working for me...

Answer (score 2):

as long as the variable is defined inside the same function as the `$.ajax`-call, you should be able to use `moo` inside the `success`-callback since it's inside the closure..

However, if the `ajax`-call is made elsewhere, you have to ensure that `moo` is inside the same scope. This could be done like this:

```
function thatDefinesTheVariable () {
  var moo = 'cow noise';
  makeAjaxCall(moo);
}

function makeAjaxCall (moo) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: "",
    success: function(data){
            //return the variable here
            alert(moo);
    }
  });
}
```