# How to update raty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, raty

I am using [jquery raty plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/), there is a [click event](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/#click) which I am using to send rating data and then return new rating from database, but I cant figure out how to update returned rating, my code:

```
    $('.starrating').raty({
            number:10,
            score: function() {
                  return $(this).attr('data-rating');
                 },
            click: function(score, evt) {
                var contentid = $(this).attr('id');
                $.post('/main/rating.php',{score:score, contentid:contentid },
                        function(data){
                            //alert(data+' Score = '+score);
                            $(this).data('rating',2);
                });
            }
            });
```

I tried with below but no success;

```
$(this).data('rating',2);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By setting `$.fn.data` you only setting jquery data cache linked to element. Not even real data attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$(this).raty({ score: 2 });` according to raty docs

P.S. if you additionaly need to set data attribute you can try this: `$(this).raty({ score: 2 }).attr('data-rating', 2);`

P.P.S. Little `click` event update for right handling multiple elements

```
$('.starrating').raty({
    number:10,
    score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating');
    },
    click: function(score, evt) {
        var target = $(this),
            contentid = target.attr('id');

        $.post('/main/rating.php',{score:score, contentid:contentid },
            function(data){
                target
                    .raty({
                        score: data.score
                    })
                    .attr('data-rating', data.score);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already have that, I have to update rating value dynamically.

Comment: Well Thank you It works but not with $(this) but with element name $('.starrating'),  and I have to re-add all params in .raty({params}) in callabck, its not very efficient way but since there is no other way I can find so thanks marking it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Had some trouble with this, this worked for me:

```
$('.rating').raty('score', score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments about your parameters being reset, I've added some ideas below.

```
   //SET RATY DEFAULTS  
        $.fn.raty.defaults.path = 'img';
        $.fn.raty.defaults.cancel = true;
        //etc
```

In your success function, reset the rating with the new data. Only options specified will be overridden.

```
$(this).raty('set', { option: value });
```

For example, update score

```
$(this).raty('set', { score: 2 });
```

If you are having trouble with `this`, try the code below (based on this answer [Passing variables through to AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042122/passing-variables-through-to-ajax))

```
$.fn.raty.defaults.click= function(score, evt) 
{   
    var target = $(this),
    contentid = target.attr('id');
    postvalue(score,target, contentid);
}

function postvalue (score,target, contentid)
{
    $.post('/main/rating.php',{score:score, contentid:contentid },
    function(data)
    {
         target.raty({score: data.score}).attr('data-rating', data.score);
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** None of this code has been tested.